# Data transmission between nodes and client cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-transfer

I am new to Cassandra and learning it. 
So question is how communication is done between nodes in Cassandra

1. Basic communication - failure detection and other
2. Data transmission from node to node and client
3. Any other type of communication

Answer of 1st one is Gossip protocol http://www.datastax.com/resources/faq
But I am little curious about protocol and methodology Cassandra uses to transfer data from one node to another or client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between nodes is through Gossip, as stated by you.

Failure detection is again through Gossip, each node checks for Gossip messages from other nodes. If it does not receive 'n'(configurable in `cassandra.yaml` file) number of gossip messages it considers the node as dead. Look for the tag phi-convict threshold.

I am not sure what cassandra uses for data transfer, mostly probably might be simple layers built over TCP. One of the major features of cassandra is that you don't have to worry about how Cassandra handles replication, you only have to think about the strategy

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra inter node communication is separate to communication between nodes and clients.

1. Gossip - is used so that nodes are aware of failures (client not
   involved)
2. This needs to be split: Nodes communicate/send data the storage_port (see cassandra.yaml - default port 7000), clients connect to port 9042 (or 9160 for old thrift clients) and communicate with a proprietary binary protocol specified here: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/native_protocol_v3.spec
3. Other communication you might care about is JMX, which node tool uses

More details here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureFireWall_r.html